# Small confusion about a proof in Lang's Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is a small part in the proof of Theorem 7.8. in Serge Lang's algebra: we have a PID $R$ and a finite free $R$-module $F$, as well as a submodule $M\subseteq F$. Then for every functional $\lambda\in \operatorname{Hom}_R(F,R)$ we denote by $J_\lambda$ the ideal $\lambda(M)\subseteq R$, and we choose $\lambda_1\in\operatorname{Hom}_R(F,R)$ such that $J_{\lambda_1}$ is maximal among the $J_\lambda$. Say we have $J_{\lambda_1}=(a_1)$ with $\lambda_1(x_1)=a_1$. Now he claims that for any other functional $g\in \operatorname{Hom}_R(F,R)$ we must have $g(x_1)\in (a_1)$, by maximality. However, this I don't see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $d$ be a gcd of $g(x_1)$ and $a_1$. Note that $(d)$ contains $(a_1)$. As $R$ is PID there are $a,b\in R$ such that $ag(x_1)+ba_1 = d$. Then $J_{ag+b\lambda_1}$ contains $(d)$ and then by maximality of $J_{\lambda_1}$ we get $(d)=(a_1)$, i.e. $a_1 \mid g(x_1)$.

Comment: @AlexWertheim It could be a unit. Note that the $J_{\lambda_1}$ is a maximal element of the set $\{J_{\lambda}\}_\lambda$. It doesn't need to be maximal as an ideal of the ring itself.